# configure: error: Python interpreter is too old

Tags: python, apache, gnu, thrift

I am trying to Build and Install the Apache Thrift compiler and libraries

As shown in instructions run `./configure && make`

And I get this error **configure: error: Python interpreter is too old**

I have python 2.7.12

```
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /usr/bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking whether UID '197608' is supported by ustar format... yes
checking whether GID '197121' is supported by ustar format... yes
checking how to create a ustar tar archive... gnutar
checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
checking pkg-config is at least version 0.9.0... yes
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.exe
checking for suffix of executables... .exe
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking whether gcc understands -c and -o together... yes
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for g++... g++
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether g++ accepts -g... yes
checking dependency style of g++... gcc3
checking build system type... x86_64-pc-msys
checking host system type... x86_64-pc-msys
checking how to print strings... printf
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /usr/bin/sed
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /usr/bin/grep
checking for egrep... /usr/bin/grep -E
checking for fgrep... /usr/bin/grep -F
checking for ld used by gcc... c:/mingw/mingw32/bin/ld.exe
checking if the linker (c:/mingw/mingw32/bin/ld.exe) is GNU ld... yes
checking for BSD- or MS-compatible name lister (nm)... /c/MinGW/bin/nm
checking the name lister (/c/MinGW/bin/nm) interface... BSD nm
checking whether ln -s works... no, using cp -pR
checking the maximum length of command line arguments... 24000
checking whether the shell understands some XSI constructs... yes
checking whether the shell understands "+="... yes
checking how to convert x86_64-pc-msys file names to x86_64-pc-msys format... func_convert_file_noop
checking how to convert x86_64-pc-msys file names to toolchain format... func_convert_file_noop
checking for c:/mingw/mingw32/bin/ld.exe option to reload object files... -r
checking for objdump... objdump
checking how to recognize dependent libraries... unknown
checking for dlltool... dlltool
checking how to associate runtime and link libraries... printf %s\n
checking for ar... ar
checking for archiver @FILE support... @
checking for strip... strip
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking command to parse /c/MinGW/bin/nm output from gcc object... ok
checking for sysroot... no
checking for mt... no
checking if : is a manifest tool... no
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking for dlfcn.h... yes
checking for objdir... .libs
checking if gcc supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions... no
checking for gcc option to produce PIC... -fPIC -DPIC
checking if gcc PIC flag -fPIC -DPIC works... no
checking if gcc static flag -static works... yes
checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
checking whether the gcc linker (c:/mingw/mingw32/bin/ld.exe) supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether -lc should be explicitly linked in... yes
checking dynamic linker characteristics... no
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
checking if libtool supports shared libraries... no
checking whether to build shared libraries... no
checking whether to build static libraries... yes
checking how to run the C++ preprocessor... g++ -E
checking for ld used by g++... c:/mingw/mingw32/bin/ld.exe
checking if the linker (c:/mingw/mingw32/bin/ld.exe) is GNU ld... yes
checking whether the g++ linker (c:/mingw/mingw32/bin/ld.exe) supports shared libraries... no
checking for g++ option to produce PIC... -fPIC -DPIC
checking if g++ PIC flag -fPIC -DPIC works... no
checking if g++ static flag -static works... yes
checking if g++ supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking if g++ supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
checking whether the g++ linker (c:/mingw/mingw32/bin/ld.exe) supports shared libraries... no
checking dynamic linker characteristics... no
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... (cached) yes
checking for bison... yes
checking for bison version >= 2.5... yes
checking for bison... bison -y
checking for flex... flex
checking lex output file root... lex.yy
checking lex library... none needed
checking whether yytext is a pointer... no
checking whether ln -s works... no, using cp -pR
checking for gawk... (cached) gawk
checking for ranlib... (cached) ranlib
checking whether g++ supports C++11 features by default... no
checking whether g++ supports C++11 features with -std=c++11... yes
checking for boostlib >= 1.53.0... configure: We could not detect the boost libraries (version 1.53 or higher). If you have a staged boost library (still not installed) please specify $BOOST_ROOT in your environment and do not give a PATH to --with-boost option.  If you are sure you have boost installed, then check your version number looking in <boost/version.hpp>. See http://randspringer.de/boost for more documentation.
checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
checking for openssl/ssl.h in /usr/local/ssl... no
checking for openssl/ssl.h in /usr/lib/ssl... no
checking for openssl/ssl.h in /usr/ssl... no
checking for openssl/ssl.h in /usr/pkg... no
checking for openssl/ssl.h in /usr/local... no
checking for openssl/ssl.h in /usr... no
checking whether compiling and linking against OpenSSL works... no
checking for libevent >= 1.0... no
checking for zlib >= 1.2.3... no
checking for QT... no
checking for QT5... no
checking for GLIB... no
checking for GOBJECT... no
checking for MONO... no
checking for MONO... no
checking for MONO... no
checking for javac and java... yes
checking for ant... no
checking for ant version > 1.7... expr: syntax error
no
checking for erl... no
checking for erlc... no
checking for nodejs... no
checking for node... no
checking for npm... no
checking for a Lua interpreter with version >= 5.2... none
checking for trial... no
checking whether C:\Python27\Lib version is >= 2.4... no
```

Couldn't find in documentation of Apache Thrift which python interpreter I should have on my pc.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just built Apache Thrift here, version 0.9.3. Check the PYTHON environment variable, as it should point to a valid Python interpreter that fits the version requirement >= 2.4. It could be that ./configure is looking for the Python interpreter using an invalid path.

Here's an example of what I did, and worked.

```
PYTHON="/usr/bin/python2.7" ./configure
```

But this, using an invalid, non-existing Python interpreter, gave me the error you mentioned:

```
PYTHON="/usr/bin/nonexisting-python-interpreter" ./configure
configure: error: Python interpreter is too old
```